# Accessing Groups Created in Office 365 in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, onedrive-for-business, share

I've created a Group in the Office 365 admin area and added a couple of users. However I can't seem to find it through the API.

When you go to share a file and use the search function it appears in the list. Can I access this through the API. I've attached a couple of screen shots which will hopefully make it clearer.
[image: Test Group Created in Office 365]

[image: Searching for TestGroup]

It would could if I could access users and groups through the same api also